# Dual Boot on Linux PC

Tags: windows

When I bought my laptop it had Windows on it. I soon installed Linux as a second operating system on my computer, leaving Windows on it. Recently my hard drive crashed, so when I got a new hard drive the first thing I did was re-install linux. Now I in need of re-installing windows (I already have a copy on DVD). So, how do I install windows?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You should use a VM with VirtualBox or Qemu.

If you are willing to risk it:

1. Create a partition to host your Windows installation (I use *Disks* because it comes with my distro, you can also use *fdisk*, *gparted* or something else).
2. Run your Windows installation by either:

   1. Restart your PC with the Windows disk.
   2. Make an image of the Windows disk and run it with Qemu with your hard drive mapped.

> qemu -hda /dev/sda -cdrom winxp.iso -boot d --enable-kvm
>
> Reinstall GRUB following this guide: [Reinstalling GRUB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2)
>
> Note that, if you used the qemu approach, it's likely that your system is working and reinstalling GRUB would be as easy as

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```